# Footer font size too big in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I am having a problem developing a web page, http://prime-mmorpg.tk/templetetest.php is the page, if you look at the footer in IE, it is 20 times bigger then it should be, like it is in FireFox. What is wrong with this? I am using no sizing CSS or anything for the footer, it is the same as the body, and yet it is huge. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried validating your HTML and CSS? You almost certainly have a coding error in there somewhere and that will help you find it.

Comment: No, I'll go do that right now...

Comment: Did you fix it already? The footer fonts appear to be the same size between IE8 and FF3.6.6 for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are tons of validation issues with the page; lots of unneccessary tags and tags that aren't closed.

For some reason IE believes the first center tag you have down there is 24pt, that's why it's displaying that large, although I'm not sure where it's picking up on that 24pt.  Firefox isn't applying that style.